# 2014 Subaru Forester

Tags: electrical, subaru, bluetooth

My 2014 Subaru Forester is having bad audio connection issues. I successfully linked, via Bluetooth, to my iPhone 7+ but any time I give a command: Call Mom, assign contact, etc. it's as if the receiving speakers are deaf and nothing is coming across clearly.  It won't allow voice overs (from previous car owner) either.

This is getting very frustrating what with trying to be all 'hands free'.  Please, help.

Comment: Hi and welcome!  Is this car new to you and this is the first you've tried using Bluetooth?  Is there some kind of "reset" in the owner's manual?  Please update your question with details.